# Creating an object that can hold id and value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Right now this method is creating a button that can hold both the id and value, it is done so through the merge attribute value. How can I make it so that it is not a button, instead just an object, a I can pass a command like: RowID(32, "objectid");

```
public static string RowPair(string btnValue, string btnID)
{
    string buttonHtml;
    var btnBuilder = new TagBuilder("button");
    btnBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", btnValue);
    btnBuilder.MergeAttribute("id", btnID);
    buttonHtml = btnBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    return buttonHtml;
}
```

Comment: I feel like we need some more supporting information about the scenario.  Can you maybe include some detail about what it is you're trying to accomplish?  It looks like you're creating html to store information in.  Are you just wanting html that isn't a button?  Are you wanting an entirely different convention to store this command?  What are you planning to do with the information?

Comment: Do you want to just create an object that holds two values?

Comment: @mindOfAi it needs to hold a dnyamic value(int) and an an id which can be a static string

Comment: So, KeyValuePair?

Comment: @mindOfAi yes that is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a KeyValuePair object. It stores a key and a value, obviously. Use it like this:

```
var btnBuilder = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(btnID, btnValue);
```

Hope it helps!